# How to add a tab-space at the inital part of pdfmake text

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

Is it possible to add a tab space before the beginning of the text in pdfmake. I did try "\t" for this but it does not work when we add it to the initial or before the string starts.

this is what i tries out

> 

```
var dd = {
>         content: [{
>     text: 'Cost',
>     style: 'header',
>     decoration: 'underline' }, {
>     text: '\tInvesting in a granulator is a wise move because of the enormous long-term savings of virgin raw materials and other benefits
> that you gain.',
>     style: 'para' }],
>         styles: {
>             header: {
>                 fontSize: 20,
>                 bold: true
>             },
>             para: {
>                 fontSize: 10,
>                 margin: [0, 9, 0, 9]             
>             }
> 
> }
```

presently my output is:-

> Cost
>
> Investing in a granulation is a wise move because of the enormous
>   long-term savings of virgin raw materials and other benefits  that you
>   gain.

What iam looking for is a tab space before "Investing in a granulation"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add multiple "\t" to the initial string for tab space effect.

```
var dd = {
>         content: [{
>     text: 'Cost',
>     style: 'header',
>     decoration: 'underline' }, {
>     text: '\t\t\t Investing in a granulator is a wise move because of the enormous long-term savings of virgin raw materials and other benefits
> that you gain.',
>     style: 'para' }],
>         styles: {
>             header: {
>                 fontSize: 20,
>                 bold: true
>             },
>             para: {
>                 fontSize: 10,
>                 margin: [0, 9, 0, 9]             
>             }
> 
> }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this one `\u200B\t`, it's a [zero width space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) followed by a tab.

Other solutions can be found here: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/1566

Comment: This actually worked! The triple \t from the other answer didn't.

Answer (score 2):

updated solution.

```
{ text: 'My Text', preserveLeadingSpaces: true}
```